# MAPI SetsearchCriteria vs Restrict vs FindRw

Tags: c++, winapi, outlook, mapi

I'm trying to build a simple search to look for specific mails within an account in all sub-folder - **recursively**.

The current method i'm familiar with is SearchFolder + SetSearchCriteria + AdviseCallback + Large GetMessage loop until the callback i registered gets signed with the ***fnevSearchComplete*** flag.

This is great, but for accounts with over 10K mails, the search process consumes lots of resources (CPU & processing time), and in addition everything is blocked due to the nasty GetMessage loop. Is there a way to search within all subfolders(multiple tables) and simultaneously gather the found mails until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not run a message loop (GetMesage/TranlateMesage/DispatchMessage). Either use contents table notifications (they will still fire) or poll the search folder periodically using a timer.

Comment: Managed to do so with table notifications, but i got couple of question regarding the following method, is it possible that my search criteria retrieves each time 30 rows? as depicted by IAdviseSink::OnNotify::CNotify?

and more importantly, what's the life span of the LPNOTIFICATION pointer? should i copy everything immeaditly in the callback using ScDupPropset or is it safe to send the pointer as is using SendMessage to another thread for processing? my reference is: MSDN, MFCMapi::AdviseSink.cpp::OnNotify() which SendMessage to ContentsTableListCtrl.cpp::msgOnAddItem

Comment: LPNOTIFICATION pointer is only valid within the callback. If you are using SendMesage, the call is synchronous, so you don't need to duplicate the structure, but taking too long opt process the notification can cause you to lose some notifications. You'd be better off duplication the structure and using PostMessage to return from the event notification as fast as possible.

Comment: One last question, if I'm listening to TABLE_ROW_ADDED(fnevObjectModified), is there a way for me to actually know when the search is completed? as if i had to initialize my folder search's advisesink with fnevSearchComplete?

Comment: fnevSearchComplete is what you need to use. Or check the search folder state.

Comment: But according to MSDN, IMAPITABLE::ADvise doesn't support this flag, only the ObjectModified flag. is it possible to listen to both SearchCompleted and ObjectModifed altogether ?

Comment: For fnevSearchComplete , you will need to use IMsgStore::Advise and pass the entry id of the search folder.

Comment: Couple of questions? can i use the same AdviseSink for both objects? IMsgStore and IMApiTable? when i do, i see that SearchCompleted arrives before any search results? and for searches which contain large amount of results, i receive only the TABLE_CHANGE notification

Comment: I don't see why you can't use the same sink. TABLE_CHANGE is expected for a large number of items.

Comment: Is there a way to keep receiving the TABLE_ROW_ADDED instead of the TABLE_CHANGED event? i'm interested in being notified on the fly rather than wait to the end and only then process the records (SearchCompleted)

Comment: No, the store provider sends TABLE_CHANGED if there were too many changes to send separate notifications for each one. TABLE_CHANGED  is raised less often if your event handler handing  TABLE_ROW_ADDED is fast (just store the data and immediately return).

Comment: But im not getting TABLE_ROW_ADDED at all, just TABLE_CHANGED

Comment: Yes, if the store provider doesn't want to bother with multiple TABLE_ROW_ADDED  (for whatever reason), you get TABLE_CHANGED. You don't get to pick.

Comment: What kind of information can i get from this event? it's not like i even know what was changed within the table

Comment: Exactly. TABLE_CHANGED means too many things have changed and you must assume that everything must be reloaded.

Comment: Got it, so i basically have to wait for the SEARCH_COMPLETED event to arrive... that's not going to help me too much with speeding things up(process the mails simultaneously to the search)